# How to return appended data frame using a function in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, function, append

I would like to return each data frame from each URL appended into one single data frame. When I print it within the function, I get the result I desire. The problem is when I try assign a variable to the data frame, it only adds the final data frame. Running this function prints my desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
urllist = ['https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/boxscore/2022-04-09/Indiana-at-Philadelphia/388705', 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/boxscore/2022-04-09/New-Orleans-at-Memphis/388704', 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/boxscore/2022-04-09/Golden-State-at-San-Antonio/388706', 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/boxscore/2022-04-09/Sacramento-at-LA-Clippers/388703']
def Boxscore(URL):
    for x in URL:
        box_list = pd.read_html(x)
        box1 = box_list[3]
        box2 = box_list[4]
        fullbox = pd.concat([box1, box2])
        print(fullbox)

Boxscore(urllist)
```

But when I try to assign it a value, it only prints the final data frame, instead of all of them together.

```
import pandas as pd
urllist = ['https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/boxscore/2022-04-09/Indiana-at-Philadelphia/388705', 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/boxscore/2022-04-09/New-Orleans-at-Memphis/388704', 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/boxscore/2022-04-09/Golden-State-at-San-Antonio/388706', 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/boxscore/2022-04-09/Sacramento-at-LA-Clippers/388703']
def Boxscore(URL):
    for x in URL:
        box_list = pd.read_html(x)
        box1 = box_list[3]
        box2 = box_list[4]
        fullbox = pd.concat([box1, box2])
    return fullbox

fullboxscore = Boxscore(urllist)
print(fullboxscore)
```

How can I append each data frame into one, and name that new data frame as a variable? Please help, thanks!

Comment: Avoid those way-too-abstract "dataframe", "function" and "append" tags. Those are all generic programming concepts and you don't want to tag your question with them unless it was also very generic and abstract. The "pandas" tag is the actual one you should use, as it represents the framework causing your struggles and is what potential answerers will be subscribed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an empty list to append to and then concat

```
def Boxscore(URL: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    dfs = [] # empty list
    for x in URL:
        box_list = pd.read_html(x)
        box1 = box_list[3]
        box2 = box_list[4]
        fullbox = pd.concat([box1, box2])
        dfs.append(fullbox) # append frame to list
        
    return pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True) # concat frames and return

# call you function and assign it to a variable 
fullboxscore = Boxscore(urllist)
```

Comment: Thank you man this worked, you're a legend!

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it worked for you. Good luck on your project.